# Airflow setting dag depends on past with trigger rule

Tags: python, airflow

I have a dag that sets depends_on_past=True. So for most task we want this to hold.
And a particular task A, we set trigger_rule="one_failed"

The problem is. This task A don't always get triggered cause it's parents don't always fail. But if it doesn't get triggered everyday (say if we schedule everyday), then depends_on_past condition won't be met.

Meaning. If day 1 didn't run. Then day 2 if a task fails, it doesn't run!

How do I set this BashOperator to ignore depends_on_past rule?

Answer (score 1):

You can overwrite `depends_on_past` parameter for specific task instance. So in your case, task A's definition can overwrite `depends_on_past=False`, while the rest of the tasks within your DAG still run with the value of `depends_on_past=True`.